# Componetizing Web Server

Tags: web-apps, web-development, web-server

I want to build a website where it will be useful to nest templates like so:

```
<form>
    <foo-input></foo-input>
    <bar-input if="hasABar(this)"></bar-input>
</form>
```

where `this` is some object and this is a form for modifying one. This is what I mean by "Componentizing" - I'm looking for advanced templating that's capable of breaking a complex site into easily digestible parcels. If this looks/sounds like Angular, it's because that's what I was looking at first. But the problem with Angular is that a simple hello world page includes ~0.5MB of Javascript (minified) *even when using server-side rendering and the controller does nothing on the front end*. That's frankly unacceptable, especially because Angular seems to enforce "single-page 'apps'".

My site will inevitably use some Javascript for niceties like sortable tables, and I'd like to write that with Typescript. I'd also like to write styling in SCSS syntax. Because of these two things (mostly that first one), I'll probably wind up using Node, so although it kills me I must prefer a node-based framework. But don't let that stop you from suggesting something that isn't node-based if it fits the other criteria.

What server/framework should I use?

Comment: Please explain downvotes so I can improve the question.

Comment: What does "Componetizing" mean? It is not an English word.

Comment: I am not the person who downvoted but I guess they downvoted because the `barf`s and `I'll probably wind up using ..., so although it kills me I must prefer ...` are just ranting, and make the whole text look bad.

Comment: By the way, there is no question, you might want to fix that.

Comment: In the worst case, you can minimize the JS

Comment: I mean, the question is sort of implicit based on where we are. I want software recommendations. As far as my rant, I'm not going to obscure my preferences and opinions - those are important to consider when giving me software recommendations. I actually can't think of a better word than "componentize", it's not mere templates it's breaking things down into their components. I'll explain that in the post, but I'm open to suggestions for synonyms.

Comment: @Mawg even minimized it's still about 0.5MB of javascript that never gets used.

Comment: Not a major overhead, even on mobile devices, but still unnecessary, I agree.  The best that you can hope for is that it gets cached, so that it will only be downloaded once.

Comment: AngularJS (1.x) can be done in line, use templates, etc. but doesn't generate massive files.  Also about to be not supported.  Might want to look at `vuejs` for similar functionality w/o going with full blow Angular (2.x+)